# Dagger: Inject field on provided pojo

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

Currently testing with dagger, what I want to do is instantiate and inject different Bar implementations. How can I inject fields in provided fields? 
for example:

Module:

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                Main.class
        },
        complete = false,
        library = true
)
public class ExampleTestModule {
    @Provides
    public Foo providesFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
    @Provides
    public Bar providesBar(BarImpl impl) {
        // return new BarImpl(); // null
        return impl;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    @Inject
    Foo foo;
}
```

Foo:

```
public class Foo {
    @Inject
    Bar bar;
}
```

Bar:

```
public interface Bar {

}
```

BarImpl

```
public class BarImpl implements Bar {
}
```

TestCase:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }


    public void testFoo() {
        Main main = new Main();
        ObjectGraph.create(new ExampleTestModule()).inject(main);
        assertNotNull(main.foo);
    }

    public void testFooBar() {
        Main main = new Main();
        ObjectGraph.create(new ExampleTestModule()).inject(main);
        assertNotNull(main.foo.bar);
    }
}
```

Main.Foo is not null but Main.Foo.Bar is null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are never injecting `bar` into `foo`.

```
ObjectGraph.create(new ExampleTestModule()).inject(main);
```

This line will only look at the fields of `main` which are annotated by `@Inject`, and inject them. There is no recursive behavior.

---

### Fixing the problem

Let's go step-by-step:

- You provided `complete = false` and `library = true` in your `Module`. You should only use these if really necessary. Dagger will give you warnings when something is wrong, and these properties surpress these warnings. For example, removing them raises the following warning when compiling:

  ```
  Error:(11, 8) error: No injectable members on BarImpl. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by providesBar(BarImpl) for ExampleTestModule.
  ```
- Let's add an empty injectable constructor to `BarImpl`, as it suggests:

  ```
  public class BarImpl implements Bar {
      @Inject
      BarImpl(){
      }
  }
  ```
- Compiling will give a new error:

  ```
  Error:(11, 8) error: Graph validation failed: You have these unused @Provider methods:
  1. ExampleTestModule.providesBar()
  Set library=true in your module to disable this check.
  ```
- Apparently, `providesBar()` is never used. That means, the `bar` field in `Foo` will never be injected. You can do two things:

  1. Inject `bar` manually:

     ```
     ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(new ExampleTestModule());
     graph.inject(main);
     graph.inject(main.foo);
     ```
  2. Use injectable constructors (Preferred option):

     ```
     public class Foo {
         Bar bar;

         @Inject
         Foo(Bar bar){
             this.bar = bar;
         }
     }
     ```
- Using the injectable constructor, you will now have a compile error in `providesFoo()`, since you don't supply a `Bar` instance in the `Foo` constructor. The nice thing about Dagger is, you can safely completely remove this method. Since `Foo` is annotated with `@Injectable`, everywhere it needs to inject a `Foo` instance, it uses this constructor. And when it uses this constructor, it notices it needs a `Bar` instance, and injects this as well.
- Finally, we can remove the `@Inject` annotation from the `Foo` field in `Main`, and create an injectable constructor. Using `ObjectGraph.get(Class<?>)` we can retrieve a fully instantiated `Main` instance.

---

### The result

The end result should look like this:

**Module:**

```
@Module(
        injects = Main.class
)
public class ExampleTestModule {
    @Provides
    public Bar providesBar(BarImpl impl) {
        return impl;
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
public class Main {
    Foo foo;

    @Inject
    Main(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

**Foo:**

```
public class Foo {
    Bar bar;

    @Inject
    Foo(Bar bar){
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

**Bar:**

```
public interface Bar {
}
```

**BarImpl:**

```
public class BarImpl implements Bar {
    @Inject
    BarImpl(){
    }
}
```

**ApplicationTest:**

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {

    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }


    public void testFoo() {
        Main main = ObjectGraph.create(new ExampleTestModule()).get(Main.class);
        assertNotNull(main.foo);
    }

    public void testFooBar() {
        Main main = ObjectGraph.create(new ExampleTestModule()).get(Main.class);
        assertNotNull(main.foo.bar);
    }
}
```

---

### Conclusion

From the result, we can conclude some things:

- Don't just add `library = true` and `complete = false` to your module. This should only be necessary when using multiple complex modules.
- Try to use injectable constructors. This is what Dagger's built for, and works best. An extra perk is that you can now have your fields `private`, like they should be.
- When using injectable constructors, you really only need to create `providesXXX` methods when injecting instances of interfaces, like we did with `Bar` and `BarImpl`. *Because, hey, that's exactly what Dependency Injection is for, right?*

Comment: Do I need to add @Inject annotation even on no-args constructor? Like on BarImpl. Also what's the difference between providesBar which return the parameter and providesBar which return newly created instance of Bar?

Comment: 1. Well the point is Dagger needs the `@Inject` annotation on *a constructor*. Since you don't have any special constructors, this will be the no-args one. 2. When using the `BarImpl` parameter, you let Dagger create an instance for you. If `BarImpl` would have any injectable fields, this is done automatically (just like in the `Foo` class). In this case, you could trivially return a new `BarImpl` instance yourself.

Comment: There are multiple ways to get everything to work, my understanding is that this is the way Dagger was intended to be used.

Comment: This comment should be on Dagger page one.